# Swift: Simple DispatchQueue does not run & notify correctly

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

What i am doing wrong? At playground it runs as it should. But as soon as i deploy it on iOS simulator it returns the wrong sequence.

```swift
@objc func buttonTapped(){

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)

    for i in 1...4 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
            print(" \(i)")  
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    for i in 1...4 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
            print("❌ \(i)")
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("jobs done by group")
    }   
}
```

**Console Output:**

[image: ios-Simulator]
[image: playground]

I don't get it.

Comment: Your code makes no attempt to control the order of anything running. The group only ensures the final print is done after all of the other prints (once you fix the calls to `leave`).

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the explanation. By what means can I control the process (when running a lot of dependent functions) without getting into completion handler hell?

Comment: Start by updating your question to tell us the desired order of output. And if you want thing done in the order 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 then explain why you are using queues at all.

Comment: i think i should open a new question about it. this was just for understanding GCD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the `group.leave()` statement in the `dispatchQueue.async` block as well, otherwise it will be executed synchronously before the async block would finish execution.

```
@objc func buttonTapped(){

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)

    for i in 1...4 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
            print(" \(i)")  
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    for i in 1...4 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
            print("❌ \(i)")
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("jobs done by group")
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works smoother now. But the loop is not running correctly?  2
 3
 1
 4
❌ 1
❌ 2
❌ 3
❌ 4
jobs done by group

https://imgur.com/a/Xhet2gp

Comment: @TyrusRechs it seems like you're misunderstanding how dispatch groups are supposed to work. You can execute any number of tasks asynchronously on in the group, on a dispatch queue. The number of `notify` only makes sure that whatever is in the execution block of `group.notify` will only be called once the number of `group.enter()` and `group.leave()` statements level out, such that nothing is in the group.

Comment: okay, did I get it right? The tasks are all performed asynchronously, regardless of their time of completion.  However, when all tasks of the group are finished, the notification is sent.

Comment: @TyrusRechs yes, that's the gist of it

Answer (score 1):

As [Dávid said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543358/1271826), properly employed dispatch groups only ensure that the notification takes place after all of the tasks finish, which you can achieve by calling `leave` from within the dispatched blocks, as he showed you. Or alternatively, since your dispatched tasks are, themselves, synchronous, you don't have to manually `enter` and `leave` the `group`, but can use `group` parameter of `async` method:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)

for i in 1...4 {
    queue.async(group: group) {
        print(" \(i)")
    }
}

for i in 1...4 {
    queue.async(group: group) {
        print("❌ \(i)")
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("jobs done by group")
}
```

Use `group.enter()` and `group.leave()` when calling some asynchronous method, but in the case of these `print` statements, you can just use [`async(group:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300095-async) as shown above.

Now, we've solved the problem where the "jobs done by group" block didn't wait for all of the dispatched tasks. But, because you're doing all of this dispatching to a concurrent queue (all the global queues are concurrent queues), you have no assurances that your tasks will be performed in the order that you requested. They're queued up in a strict FIFO manner, but because they're concurrent, you have no assurances when you'll hit the respective `print` statements.

If you need it to print the messages in order, you will have to use a serial queue. For example, if you create your own queue, in the absence of the [`.concurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/attributes/2300052-concurrent) attribute, the following will create a serial queue:

```
// create serial queue

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "...")

// but not your own concurrent queue:
//
// let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "...", attributes: .concurrent)
//
// nor one of the global concurrent queues:
//
// let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)
//
```

And if you run the above code with this serial queue, you'll see what you were looking for:

> 1
>    2
>    3
>    4
>   ❌ 1
>   ❌ 2
>   ❌ 3
>   ❌ 4
>   jobs done by group

But, then, again, if you were using a serial queue, the `group` would be completely unnecessary (you could just add the "completion" task as yet another dispatched task at the end of the serial queue). I only show the use of serial queues as a way to avoid the race condition of dispatching eight tasks to a concurrent queue.

Comment: By the way, Tyrus, please do _not_ unaccept Dávid's answer. He is correct. I just wanted to clarify.