# Does the swift REPL support async DispatchQueue?

Tags: swift, multithreading, read-eval-print-loop

I am tinkering with concurrency in `swift` and am suspicious that the `REPL` is not actually running the `DispatchQueue` as it would happen in a live app.  I have copied and pasted code from a couple of questions including this one [Swift: Simple DispatchQueue does not run & notify correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543334/swift-simple-dispatchqueue-does-not-run-notify-correctly):

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)

for i in 1...4 {
    queue.async(group: group) {
        print(" \(i)")
    }
}

for i in 1...4 {
    queue.async(group: group) {
        print("❌ \(i)")
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("jobs done by group")
}
```

Now when pasting this into the `repl`  I see some old queue items and some new ones - but not *all* of the expected new ones.

```
 2
 4
image
video
 3
group: DispatchGroup = {
  baseOS_dispatch_object@0 = {
    baseOS_object@0 = {
      baseNSObject@0 = {
        isa = OS_dispatch_group
      }
    }
  }
}
queue: OS_dispatch_queue_global = {
  baseOS_dispatch_queue@0 = {
    baseOS_dispatch_object@0 = {
      baseOS_object@0 = {
        baseNSObject@0 = {
          isa = OS_dispatch_queue_global
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I type in some random additional statements .. and get to see additional queued tasks complete:

```
 96> let  x = 3
❌ 1
x: Int = 3
 97> let x = 4
video
x: Int = 4
 98> x
❌ 2
$R1: Int = 4
```

It seems clear that there are *no* background threads running.  Is there a way to get true concurrent/threaded operations within the `repl` ?

**Update** I changed the code to `.userInteractive` and that helps a little but does not address the root problem.

```
  let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)
```

The results are still only happening in fits and spurts.  Adding `Thread.sleep()` causes it to break:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)

    for i in 1...5 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
            print(" \(i)")  
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    for i in 1...6 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
            print("❌ \(i)")
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("jobs done by group")
}
```

We only get a subset of the results and there is no `sleep` happening between them.

```
❌ 1
❌ 3
❌ 2
❌ 2
❌ 4
 2
```

So there is something else going on / needed here.

**Another update**  I just added two lines of code at the end:

```
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 20)
    print("Dispatcher done")
```

Then I ran this in the `iOS Simulator` and the behavior is somewhat different.

- The print statements do all get executed
- The `Thread.sleep()` is a *noop* inside the call to `dispatchQueue.async()`
- But the `Thread.sleep()` does take effect outside the loop *and causes the main thread to hang*.  That is expected.

Here is the output when running in `ios Simulator`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK this one was easy - it is about the `quality of service`.  Changing it to `userInteractive`

```
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
```

We now have the expected result:

```
 2
 4
❌ 4
 1
❌ 3
❌ 1
 1
 3
 3
 4
```

Here is the fully corrected code

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)

    for i in 1...4 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
            print(" \(i)")  
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    for i in 1...4 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
            print("❌ \(i)")
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("jobs done by group")
}
```

**Update**  I jumped too soon: the results are still only happening in fits and spurts.  Adding `Thread.sleep()` causes it to break:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)

    for i in 1...5 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
            print(" \(i)")  
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    for i in 1...6 {
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.async {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
            print("❌ \(i)")
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("jobs done by group")
}
```

We only get a subset of the results and there is no `sleep` happening between them.

❌ 1
❌ 3
❌ 2
❌ 2
❌ 4
 2

So there is something else going on / needed here.